# Find count of superclass without subclass

Tags: jpa, playframework

A class is a superclass and B is its subclass. I use JPA to save their instances. Is that possible to count the size of A without B?
For example, I save 10 A and 10 B. But I got 20 when I execute A.findAll().size().

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the inheritance set with one table per class? **@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)**

If so A.count() should do the trick.

Otherwise write your own query: A.count(where ...)